# Is practicing algorithms and data structures in high level languages suboptimal?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I bought a copy of Cracking the Coding Interview and want to go through the exercises. I'm well-versed in Python and Clojure and wondering whether they'd be suitable for this purpose. If I impose a strict restriction to use only lists and classes (or records) that I create, will I still gain full benefit in terms of learning (outside of memory management), or should I go back to C/Java (I haven't touched either in years)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing how to implement and when to use which algorithms and data structures is an important skill in any language, and most algorithms can be implemented in all the mainstream languages.

The point about them is scalability of programs, i.e. graceful performance degradation as inputs grow. That's much more important than the constant factor speedup you get from switching to a lower-level programming language.

Answer (score 0):

If you were writing a real program with real performance requirements, you could get some advantage of writing it in C instead of in Python. However, you are mainly interested in the algorithms to use. Almost all algorithms can be implemented in any language, so it does not matter which language you use. If you are good in Python or Clojure, use those.

Edit: an example of an "algorithm" that can not be implemented in <s>any</s> all languages is [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Answer (score 0):

I think any generic language is suitable for data structures.

However, like in Python a lot of data structures are already part of the language. Of course you can add data structures but a lot is already implemented and thus not needed to go through again (unless you want to know the internals a bit better).

Maybe it's also useful to think wether it is useful to dive deep into data structures at all (meaning: does Python provide enough or is it just a matter of knowledge gathering).

Comment: It's mostly for knowledge gathering for the purposes of answering more comp-sci related interview questions. For example, I may need to know about the different ways to hash rather than using a straight Clojure map or Python dict. Or be able to implement a priority queue as a heap to model an order book, etc.

Comment: Ok in that case it is not really about the implementation but the usage, which is very important. I don't think you should go back to C just because of (the lack) of data structures. You can use the data structures available in Python which you need (after reading the interviews you should have a good knowledge which to use) and if it is not available in Python, create it (it's much easier than in C).